# PHP regex match any string ending with asterisk

Tags: php, regex

I have a php 7 app and I want to match some patterns using regex. I have the following pattern so far:

`/=\~|=\*|=|!=|\(\)|>=|<=|>|</`

And I'm able to match any of the following:

`=~, =*,=,!=...etc.`

However, I want to match two more patterns, the first starts with `=` followed by any number of chars (including numbers and special characters) ending with an asterisk, for example: `=ijnhu9*` or `=1$n*`. The second one is `=` followed by an asterisk followed by any number of chars (including numbers and special characters). For example: `=*bfrg%1` or `=*7lk;y`. How can I add these two new patterns to my original pattern? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the alternation with the parts that you want, and put the most specific ones at the beginning.

```
=\*[^\s*=]*|=[^\s*=]*\*|=[~*]?|!=|\(\)|[<>]=?
```

- `=\*[^\s*=]*` Match `=*` optionally followed by any char except `=` or a whitespace char
- `|` Or
- `=[^\s*=]*\*` Match `=` optionanly followed by any char except `*` or `=` or a whitespace char, ending on `*`
- `|` Or
- `=[~*]?` Match `=` `=~` or `=*`
- `|` Or
- `!=` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `\(\)` Match `()`
- `|` Or
- `[<>]=?` Match `<` `>` `<=` `>=`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6YDSu/1)

Comment: Thank you it works. Could you please explain a bit about the different parts of it.

Comment: @molupq I have added a break down of the pattern so you can see what all the separate alternations match.